# Find number of every point of interest within radius and number of specific points of interest within radius using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have two shapefiles that I am a trying to compare to one another. The first set of points are various businesses. With assistance it was discovered that in order to get a subset category from that shapefile the following code should be used:

```
cat = 'ClothingStore'
arcypy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr","NEW_SELECTIION",'"category"='+"'%s'"% cat)
```

After I have isolated the subset category from the shapefile I want to compare that subset of points to another set of points that are all within a single shapefile called Churches.shp. I want to find all the ClothingStores points that are within a 500 radius of Church points.

How could this be done through ArcPy?

Comment: Have you looked at [select by location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm)?  I'd use the "within a distance" option.

Comment: Thanks. I see: SelectLayerByLocation_management (in_layer, {overlap_type}, {select_features}, {search_distance}, {selection_type}, {invert_spatial_relationship}). . . . . . . . . Would something like this work?: SelectLayerByLocation_management ('ClothingStore', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 'Churches.shp' , '500 Meters', '#', '#')

Comment: Not sure how I would specify the first in_layer as only those ClothingStore pts.

Comment: When you choose a layer that has already been subject to a select by attribute or select by location, by default it keeps your selection. What resources have you consulted for learning ArcGIS? There are some online courses including Lynda.com and other resources that might be helpful for getting familiar with the terminology and basic tools before you try to add in the arcpy component.

Comment: Thank you again. The original shp file said, DC_POI.shp, I suppose I could simple just put that as my in_layer, since it's already been established that it's only turning on ClothingStore pts. So then it would be this: SelectLayerByLocation_management ('DC_POI.shp', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 'Churches.shp' , '500 Meters', '#', '#')

Comment: OK, so if all of your businesses are DC_POI.shp, and you only want Clothing Stores and Churches, you could do something along the lines of 1) Select by attributes for churches and export the layer to a new shapefile 2) select by attributes (from DC_POI) for Clothing Stores (since you don't want the non-clothing stores within a radius of the churches) and 3) Select by location from DC_POI) within a distances of the churches.  Again, do these steps outside of Arcpy so that you can understand what it's doing, and then migrate to arcpy.

Comment: Thanks. DC_POI.shp has all sorts of businesses, but Churches.shp is just a shapefile with only all the church pt data. Would I need to select by attribute on churches still? or could I say Churches.shp?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize there were two shapefiles. Yes, you could just say churches.shp.

Comment: Note: you may need to use [make feature layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) first in order for this to work.

Comment: Using ArcMap which would be my Target layer and which would be my source layer?

Comment: Target is "what layer are you trying to find stuff within".  You want to find clothing stores. Clothing Stores (or the POI file with them) is your target.

Comment: Thanks. Okay so the targets are the ClothingStores and the source layer is the Church pts. Why do I need to create a feature layer from a layer file why can't it be just DC_POI.shp why must it be changed?

Comment: Also I decided to use another set of data, metrostations. Here is what that looks like in ArcGIS: https://imgur.com/a/gG9kGC7

Comment: Are you running arcpy within the Python window in ArcMap, or are you trying to run this in a separate window (not within ArcMap)?  These tools operate on layers; a map file with the shapefiles loaded are layers, but if you want to run this separately you need to create a layer from the shapefile first.

Comment: I am running them separate. Arcmap and then a separate wing python window for the python code.

Comment: Does the select by location meet your needs? I'm having trouble understanding your end goal, so this might not be the right tool for your task.

Comment: I want to output the number of ClothingStores within a 500 Meter radius of Churches, and then output the number of all businesses with a 500 Meter radius of Churches. Am new to Arcmap so not exactly 100% on it. It seems like that would work though.

Comment: Do you need a breakdown per church, or just pure number overall for all of DC?

Comment: Not a breakdown just the count of all clothing stores that fit within a distance of 500 meter radius of a church(es). For all of DC.

Comment: Also which would I be making a feature layer of the DC_POI or the metrostations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can solve this using a combination of select by attributes and select by location. Select by attributes first on the overall points of interest file, and then select by location to find those selected POIs (clothing stores) within a distance of the churches layer.  OR, select by location for all POIs within that distance, and subset that selection by attribute.

Check this answer for details on how to specify the distance units:
[How to specify units when using SelectLayerbyLocation_management WITHIN_A_DISTANCE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80946/how-to-specify-units-when-using-selectlayerbylocation-management-within-a-distan)

Try to use the Python window within ArcGIS first as it can walk you through creating the script. Or create a model in Model Builder and then export the Python code.

Comment: Thank you. How does this look:. . . . arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('DC_POI.shp','Clothing_lyr'). . . . .arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('MetroStations.shp,'Stations_lyr'). . . . .arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management ("Clothing_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "[NAME] = 'ClothingStore' ") . . . . . distance = 500. . . . .linearUnit = distance + " Meters" . . . . .arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(targetLayer, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", inputLayer, linearUnit)

Comment: Also would you know what this means? • Use buffer analysis to buffer the metro stations by the user-specified radius and create a new
shapefile.
• Use Select Layer By Location analysis to select all POI that intersect your new buffered dataset.
Remember that you have to make a feature layer before you do the selection.